# Product Star Ratings Summary not displaying Magento Enterprise

Tags: magento2, magento-enterprise

Star is not showing on review tab. Please help me 
Please refer this screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TF1Wk.png

Comment: rating is enable check Stores > Rating ?

Comment: yes,it is enable

Comment: multi store or single store ?

Comment: I am working on single store

Comment: magento version ?

Comment: magento enterprise version